# south african prices

Tags: quote, recorder, nagra, boom-pole, south-africa

I'm looking for a place that can give me quotes on set recorders like the nagra LB and V (or any equivalent). Preferable a south african dealer I know about vitatone I'm having trouble getting a quote from them. Also a place that stocks boom poles (preferably graphite).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

- I think [Sennheiser South Africa](http://www.sennheiser.co.za/) (next to 44 Stanley in jhb) do Nagra too... I might be wrong though. They should have boom poles.
- There's Jurgen from Vitatone for the Nagra stuff, but you know that already. You may have been struggling to get hold of him because apparently he is in hospital.
- I know [Prosound](http://www.prosound.co.za/) stock Sound Devices if you want to go that route.
- There's [Stratosphere](http://stratosphere.co.za/index.php?id=19) in Cape Town.
- Maybe [Turnkey Music](http://www.tuerkmusic.co.za), but I doubt it.

Because South Africa is so expensive with all this, I usually combine a trip overseas and buy all I need/can afford in one swoop.

Comment: what about zoom h4n? it's quite affordable, does pretty much the same job but it runs on batteries, I cab get it at toms in sandton city, ja i heard abt that place yesterday wanted to check it out but once i heard about the zoom h4n that changed a lot but ill still check the sennheiser place for boom poles, i was also told camera man for booms and zeplins

Comment: @Jm h4n is nice. Got one. I found another shop today, Music Connection on Jan Smuts (JHB). They sold me the RODE blimp for a really good price, and they where super kind and helpful with other stuff. Recommend them. They also have boom poles (or can order).

Answer (score 0):

I'm from South Africa. Where are you based?
I know a few places in Cape Town.
And I believe Andrew Spitz is still in Johannesburg.

Comment: what about zoom h4n? it's quite affordable, does pretty much the same job but it runs on batteries (AA). I'm in the old 011 (jhb) cape town is bangin'man really wanna go there again! what do you do there sound wise; film, radio, recording, producing?